Delphi - Direct2D - Paintbox drawing is flickering
Delphi 11 - Windows 64 bits
I am trying to draw various things in a TPaintBox using TDirect2D. I need to constantly update what's drawn inside. Unfortunately, my TPaintBox is flickering when I'm modifying it.
I reproduced my problem in a small simpler project.
.dfm:
    object FormMain: TFormMain
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'FormMain'
      ClientHeight = 968
      ClientWidth = 1470
      Color = clBtnFace
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWindowText
      Font.Height = -12
      Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
      Font.Style = []
      TextHeight = 15
      object PaintBox: TPaintBox
        AlignWithMargins = True
        Left = 20
        Top = 20
        Width = 1389
        Height = 928
        Margins.Left = 20
        Margins.Top = 20
        Margins.Right = 20
        Margins.Bottom = 20
        Align = alLeft
        OnMouseMove = PaintBoxMouseMove
        OnPaint = PaintBoxPaint
      end
    end

.pas:
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    PaintBox: TPaintBox;
    procedure PaintBoxMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PaintBoxPaint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Déclarations privées }
    Index: Integer;
  public
    { Déclarations publiques }
  end;

var
  FormMain: TFormMain;

implementation

uses
  Vcl.Direct2D, Winapi.D2D1;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormMain.PaintBoxMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  PaintBox.Invalidate();
end;

procedure TFormMain.PaintBoxPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  LCanvas: TDirect2DCanvas;
  Poly: array of TPoint;
begin
  LCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(PaintBox.Canvas, ClientRect);
  LCanvas.RenderTarget.SetAntialiasMode(D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_PER_PRIMITIVE);
  LCanvas.BeginDraw;

  try
    { Drawing goes here }
    LCanvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
    LCanvas.Brush.Color := clNone;
    LCanvas.Pen.Width := 5;

    SetLength(Poly, 4);
    Poly[0] := Point(LCanvas.Pen.Width div 2 + Index, LCanvas.Pen.Width div 2 + Index);
    Poly[1] := Point(PaintBox.Width - LCanvas.Pen.Width, LCanvas.Pen.Width div 2);
    Poly[2] := Point(PaintBox.Width - LCanvas.Pen.Width, PaintBox.Height - LCanvas.Pen.Width);
    Poly[3] := Point(LCanvas.Pen.Width div 2, PaintBox.Height - LCanvas.Pen.Width);
    LCanvas.Polygon(Poly);
    inc(Index);

    LCanvas.MoveTo(10, 10);
    LCanvas.LineTo(PaintBox.Width - 10 - LCanvas.Pen.Width, PaintBox.Height - 10 - LCanvas.Pen.Width);
  finally
    LCanvas.EndDraw;
    LCanvas.Free;
  end;
end;

end.

Putting the form's double buffered property to true stops the flickering. But if I put the TPaintBox inside a TPanel (whose double buffered property is also set to true), it starts flickering again, which makes me think there is another problem.
I have also tried putting my TPaintBox in a frame, and adding that frame to my form (either by interface, or dynamically, and neither worked).

Maybe you haven't read the "how-to -ask" section in the help for this site. It states (among other things) that the question must include a complete minimal reproducible example: [mre]. Specifically do not link to some external site, which may become dysfunctional at some time, rendering your question worthless. Therefore, please make sure your example code is minimal, but complete and showing the problem you ask about, and including both .pas file and .dfm file in your post here.

Look into using the Direct2D canvas exclusively as mentioned in the help Using Direct2D canvas exclusively. Read the paragraph above the section of help linked for reasons why this might be desirable.

I have updated the post to fit the guidelines. Thanks and sorry for that.
I will try looking into the Using Direct2D canvas exclusively

As @Brian said, I looked into Using Direct2D canvas exclusively.
It seems to have worked.
Here's what my small example looks like with this method:
.dfm:
    object FormMain: TFormMain
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'FormMain'
      ClientHeight = 968
      ClientWidth = 1470
      Color = clBtnFace
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWindowText
      Font.Height = -12
      Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
      Font.Style = []
      TextHeight = 15
      object Panel: TPanel
        Left = 800
        Top = 264
        Width = 377
        Height = 401
        TabOrder = 0
      end
    end

.pas:
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Direct2D;

type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    Panel: TPanel;
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;

    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  private
    { Déclarations privées }
    Index: Integer;
    FCanvas: TDirect2DCanvas;
  public
    { Déclarations publiques }
    property Canvas: TDirect2DCanvas read FCanvas;
  end;

var
  FormMain: TFormMain;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.D2D1;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormMain.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  FCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(Panel.Handle);
end;

procedure TFormMain.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  PaintStruct: TPaintStruct;
  LPoly: array of TPoint;
begin
  BeginPaint(Panel.Handle, PaintStruct);

  try
    FCanvas.BeginDraw;
    try
      FCanvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
      FCanvas.Brush.Color := clNone;
      FCanvas.Pen.Width := 5;

      SetLength(LPoly, 4);

      LPoly[0] := Point(FCanvas.Pen.Width div 2 + Index, FCanvas.Pen.Width div 2 + Index);
      LPoly[1] := Point(Panel.Width - FCanvas.Pen.Width, FCanvas.Pen.Width div 2);
      LPoly[2] := Point(Panel.Width - FCanvas.Pen.Width, Panel.Height - FCanvas.Pen.Width);
      LPoly[3] := Point(FCanvas.Pen.Width div 2, Panel.Height - FCanvas.Pen.Width);

      FCanvas.Polygon(LPoly);
      Inc(Index);
      Paint;
    finally
      FCanvas.EndDraw;
    end;
  finally
    EndPaint(Panel.Handle, PaintStruct);
  end;
end;

end.

No flickering even without double buffering.
I'm painting directly into the TPanel.
Thanks guys !
